# Generating Binary Encoded Symbols Python Program

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment that has ***instructions as follows***:

- write a program that reads in 4 sets of 4 dashed lines and outputs the four binary symbols that each set of four lines represents.
- input consists of 16 lines in total, consisting of any number of dashes and spaces.
- the first four lines represents a symbol, the next four lines represents the next symbol and so on.
- print out the four binary-encoded symbols represented by the 16 lines in total.
- each binary symbol should be on its own line

This is based upon a previous program that I wrote where input is a single line of text consisting of any number of spaces and dashes. If there is an even number of dashes in the line, output 0. Otherwise, output 1.

***This is the code for the above:***

```
 line = input()

 num_dashes = line.count("-")

 mod = num_dashes % 2

 if mod == 0:
    print("0")
 else:
    print("1")
```

Please may someone assist me?

Thank you.

Comment: What is a "binary symbol"? Is it a series of 4 binary digits?

Comment: Yes here it refers to printing a series of 4 binary digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have for processing one line is fine, although you could replace the `if...else` with just:

```
print(mod)
```

Now to extend this to multiple lines, it might be better not to call `print` like that, but to collect the output in a variable, and only output that variable when all 16 lines have been processed. This way the output does not get mixed with the input from the console.

So for instance, it could happen like this:

```
output = []
for part in range(4):  # loop 4 times
    digits = ""
    for line in range(4):   # loop 4 times
        line = input()
        num_dashes = line.count("-")
        mod = num_dashes % 2
        digits += str(mod)   # collect the digit
    output.append(digits)  # append 4 digits to a list

print("\n".join(output))  # print the list, separated by linebreaks
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot. This is very helpful!